# Passing values to PHP with JQuery AJAX not working, array confusion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've searching in the web for like 1 week and found like 15 questions asking the same thing as me, but I don't see to find the correct solution.

The problem is simple. I have a HTML table in one page and I want to pass this table thru AJAX(Jquery) and execute a php script, but I don't see where I'm doing wrong, here's all the code, I can post more if needed.

ajax by now(**the real problem here is the array definition?**):

```
$(function(){
  $('#nice_button').on('click', function(e){
    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({
        // The URL for the request
        url: "ajax_insert_suba_def.php",

        var data2 = [{
            value1 :  [1,2,3,4,5],
            value2 :  [5,4,3,2,1]
        }];

        // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
        data: { 'data': data2 },
        // Whether this is a POST or GET request
        type: "POST",
        // The type of data we expect back
        // dataType : "json",
        // Code to run regardless of success or failure
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="my_form">
    <button id="nice_button" type="button" name="btn_go" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> Insert into DB</button>
</form>
```

With some basic PHP: (the functions are ok ...  **I also need to know how to properly 'get' those values**)

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    require "includes/functions.php" ;

    $my_sqli = connect_to_mysql();

    $data = $_POST['data'];


    $val_1 = $data["value1"][0];
    $val_2 = $data["value2"][0];

    $query = "INSERT INTO test_json (test_text) VALUES('" . $val_1 . "'); ";

    $result = $my_sqli->query($query);

    $my_sqli->close();

    return "ok";

?>
```

By now the error i'm getting is this:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

(in var data2= ... line)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

You have to take `data2` outside of your AJAX request, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nice_button').on('click', function(e){

        var data2 = 
        [
            {
                value1 :  [1,2,3,4,5],
                value2 :  [5,4,3,2,1]
            }
        ]; 

        // Using the core $.ajax() method
        $.ajax({

            // The URL for the request
            url: "ajax_insert_suba_def.php",

            // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
            data: { data: data2 },

            // Whether this is a POST or GET request
            type: "POST",

            // The type of data we expect back
            // dataType : "json",

            // Code to run regardless of success or failure
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                alert( "The request is complete!" );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> I also need to know how to properly 'get' those values

This is how you can get individual values:

```
<?php

    // your code

    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $val_1 = $data[0]['value1'][0];
    $val_2 = $data[0]['value1'][1];

    // so on

    $val_5 = $data[0]['value1'][4];
    $val_6 = $data[0]['value2'][0];
    $val_7 = $data[0]['value2'][1];

    // so on

    $val_10 = $data[0]['value2'][4];

    // your code

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You made some syntax mistakes while making the AJAX call. See the **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**. You were trying to define variable inside the ajax function call options, which is supposed to be in an object format.

```
var data2 = {
    value1 :  [1,2,3,4,5],
    value2 :  [5,4,3,2,1]
};

$(function(){
  $('#nice_button').on('click', function(e){
    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({
        // The URL for the request
        url: "ajax_insert_suba_def.php",
        // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
        data: data2,
        // Whether this is a POST or GET request
        type: "POST",
        // The type of data we expect back
        // dataType : "json",
        // Code to run regardless of success or failure
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Then you'll get this as two arrays and you can get them like this.

```
value1 = $_POST['value1'];
value2 = $_POST['value2'];
```

Comment: @Stephenloky I updated the answer. I think that'll do it.

Comment: Many thanks, the php part did not work, butI used Rajdeep answ, but I've learnt what you said about the ajax part. Ty!